# Error: Cannot find module 'src/domain/email/Email'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am getting this error when running my app on test server using 'npm run dev'.

```
[nodemon] 1.19.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'src/domain/email/Email'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/app/todo/src/app/email/SendEmail.js:2:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

In my local it is running smootly.

I'm using this boilerplate to build my app : https://github.com/talyssonoc/node-api-boilerplate

Any help please!

Comment: Did you do `npm install`?
Also you may need to configure wabpack config file (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

Comment: yes, already run 'npm install' as in my local.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, it is looking for a file that does not exist, (at least not in the boilerplate), check if the files are up to date in the test server